# How to use mac typing shortcuts in iterm2?

Tags: iterm2, iterm

I want to use `⌘ + ←` to go to the first character of line and `⌘ + →` and similar shortcuts in iTerm2 but couldn't find a straight forward way to make that configuration.

I want to know if there is a one stop solution to fix this problem. Manually adding each keymap is too cumbersome.

Answer (score 3):

Solved this by adding going to `Preferences` by typing `⌘ + ,` and going to the `Profiles` tab. Selecting the  `Keys` tab in the subsection. Going to `Presets` at the bottom and selecting `Natural Text Editing`

`Profiles -> Keys -> Presets (bottom) -> Select "Natural Text Editing" option`

[image]